# add your own listener to a list

Tags: android, list, listener

i tried to add a listener to that list but nothing i don't understand why if you want to see the rest of the code please check on [add your own listener to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381211/add-your-own-listener-to-a-list)

```
public void onCreatebis(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo)  {

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            final Intent mainIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) ;
            final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> listP= (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>)                    pm.queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
            final int trimLength = "com.android.".length();
            ArrayList<String> maliste = new ArrayList<String>();
                        // Loop over each item.
            for (ResolveInfo info : listP) {
                // Get the (full, qualified) package name.
                String packag = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;

                // Now, trim it with substring and the trim length.
                String trimmed = packag.substring(trimLength);
                maliste.add(trimmed);
            }
            ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            monadaptateur adapter2 = new monadaptateur(this, maliste);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    Log.v("lalalala","lalala");

                }
                   });
            list.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if the ListView has focusable items then `onClickListener` will fire instead of the `onItemClickListener`. Set items can focus to false

```
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget). Also note there are workarounds for this. But the better choice would be to set items non focusable and use `OnItemClickListener`, or make them focusable and use an `onClickListener` on the views

Also, the `onClickListener` should not be set for the listview. Instead for each listview item in the `getView()` method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: even my log isn't display public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
          {Toast.makeText(DvpList2.this,
          "je suis là!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451947/onlistitemclick-not-working-for-listview-in-android i've seen that and even that dfoesn't work